# Trying to view the _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION structure in memory with WinDbg

Tags: structure, symbols, windbg

I'm trying to view the Windows file system structure _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION in memory using WinDbg, but for some reason it tells me that the symbol is not found.

I connected WinDbg with a pipe to a Windows XP virtual machine in order to debug its kernel.
I tried viewing the structure's data using the command `dt _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION esi` because the value of ESI is an address which contains the structure in question that I want to inspect.

All I got was the following output:

```
3: kd> dt _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION esi
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION                 ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
Symbol _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION not found.
```

Other structures are working for me, like _DRIVER_OBJECT.

All I know about the _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION symbol is that it is included in ntifs.h, according to Microsoft's documentation. I couldn't find information regarding whether this symbol is provided from Microsoft Symbol Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it appears this type info is not available in the public pdbs provided by ms

you can check yourself using wildcards

```
0: kd> dt nt!*_FILE_*
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_OBJECT
          ntkrnlmp!_PF_FILE_ACCESS_TYPE
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_SEGMENT_ELEMENT
          ntkrnlmp!_IOP_FILE_OBJECT_EXTENSION
          ntkrnlmp!_CREATE_FILE_TYPE
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_OBJECT_EXTENSION_TYPE
          ntkrnlmp!_DUMMY_FILE_OBJECT
          ntkrnlmp!_IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_GET_QUOTA_INFORMATION
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_NETWORK_OPEN_INFORMATION
          ntkrnlmp!_MMPAGE_FILE_EXPANSION
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION
          ntkrnlmp!_MAPPED_FILE_SEGMENT
          ntkrnlmp!_MMPAGE_FILE_EXPANSION_FLAGS
          ntkrnlmp!_MI_PAGING_FILE_SPACE_BITMAPS
0: kd> dt nt!*_FILE_I*
          ntkrnlmp!_FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS
```

as to view them you can view the Raw Contents of memory just do dd @esi 
and corelate them with the Structure in ntifs.h

or use .printf  and some find replace in notepad to print a formatted output

I just copy pasted the Structure From **[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_id_both_dir_information)** into notepad++
stuffed the .printf in front using find replace
stuffed the \t%x  in the end using same procedure
tweaked the offsets to the PseudoRegister and saved it as .txt

used $$>a< to run it as windbg script providing a random offset to the Pseudo Register (just made sure there is  some Unicode string at offset+0x48 
the results are as below

```
r $t0 = (fffff805`19ec53e0-48)

.printf "typedef struct _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION {                             \n"
.printf "  ULONG         NextEntryOffset;                                           \t%x\n"  , @$t0+0
.printf "  ULONG         FileIndex;                                                 \t%x\n"  , @$t0+4
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;                                              \t%N\n"  , @$t0+8
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;                                            \t%N\n"  , @$t0+10
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;                                             \t%N\n"  , @$t0+18
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;                                                \t%N\n"  , @$t0+20
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;                                                 \t%N\n"  , @$t0+28
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;                                            \t%N\n"  , @$t0+30
.printf "  ULONG         FileAttributes;                                            \t%x\n"  , @$t0+38
.printf "  ULONG         FileNameLength;                                            \t%x\n"  , @$t0+3c
.printf "  ULONG         EaSize;                                                    \t%x\n"  , @$t0+40
.printf "  CCHAR         ShortNameLength;                                           \t%x\n"  , @$t0+44
.printf "  WCHAR         ShortName[12];                                             \t%mu\n" , @$t0+48
.printf "  LARGE_INTEGER FileId;                                                    \t%N\n"  , @$t0+54
.printf "  WCHAR         FileName[1];                                               \t%mu\n" , @$t0+58
.printf "} FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, *PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION;            \n"
```

results

```
0: kd> $$>a< f:\wdscr\fileid.wds
typedef struct _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION {                              
  ULONG         NextEntryOffset;                                                19ec5398
  ULONG         FileIndex;                                                      19ec539c
  LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;                                                   FFFFF80519EC53A0
  LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;                                             FFFFF80519EC53A8
  LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;                                                  FFFFF80519EC53B0
  LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;                                                 FFFFF80519EC53B8
  LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;                                                      FFFFF80519EC53C0
  LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;                                             FFFFF80519EC53C8
  ULONG         FileAttributes;                                             19ec53d0
  ULONG         FileNameLength;                                             19ec53d4
  ULONG         EaSize;                                                     19ec53d8
  CCHAR         ShortNameLength;                                                19ec53dc
  WCHAR         ShortName[12];                                                  KeRevertToUserGroupAffinityThread
  LARGE_INTEGER FileId;                                                     FFFFF80519EC53EC
  WCHAR         FileName[1];                                                    ToUserGroupAffinityThread
} FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, *PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION;
```

Comment: Thanks! you clarified a lot for me.